# Pip won't install newest version of Django (using virtualenv)

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, webfaction

I'm trying out virtualenv for my django projects and I'm running into some hiccups. Using a webfaction account.

Right now I've got a virtualenv set up and I'm trying to install Django 1.8.2, but when I enter "pip install Django" OR "pip install Django==1.8.2" it always just installs Django-1.7.8 and uses that as the active version.

Here's some code from my command line:

```
(django_test)[pattmayne@web476 django_test]$ pip install Django==1.8.2
Collecting Django==1.8.2
  Using cached Django-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.7.8
    Not uninstalling Django at /home/pattmayne/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.8-py3.4.egg, outside environment /home/pattmayne/webapps/django_test
Successfully installed Django-1.7.8
```

Then I test the version of django-admin:

```
(django_test)[pattmayne@web476 django_test]$ django-admin.py --version
1.7.8
```

I get the same result when I try django-1.8.0 or 1.8.1

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

When I set up the virtualenv I wrote:

```
virtualenv . --no-site-packages
```

So it shouldn't even be acknowledging old installations, should it?
This is just a test case so I have no problem deleting it all and starting again.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

When I type "which django-admin.py" it uses the one inside the virtualenv. When I install with "pip install -I Django==1.8.2" it downloads the right one, but then installs the wrong one.

Here's some more output from the command line:

```
(blog_test)[pattmayne@web476 blog_test]$ pip install -I Django==1.8.2
Collecting Django==1.8.2
  Using cached Django-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django-1.7.8
(blog_test)[pattmayne@web476 blog_test]$ which django-admin.py
~/bin/django-admin.py
(blog_test)[pattmayne@web476 blog_test]$ django-admin.py --version
1.7.8
(blog_test)[pattmayne@web476 blog_test]$ bin/django-admin.py --version
-bash: bin/django-admin.py: Permission denied
(blog_test)[pattmayne@web476 blog_test]$
```

It's using something from a cache. I'll keep messing around, but any insight is still appreciated!

Comment: Is django installed in your system Python?

Comment: And `pip install -I Django==1.8.2` doesn't fix this?

Comment: @Martijin I think that worked! Now how do I change the active version? When I enter django-admin.py --version it still says "1.7.8"

Comment: @MattPayne: are you using `django-admin.py` *installed in the virtual env*?

Comment: @IanAuld  Yes, it is. Shouldn't that be irrelevant when I'm using virtualenv? I thought that's why we used virtualenv.

Comment: @Martijin I used "source bin/activate", so I was under the impression that I was using the virtual env version of django-admin. How can I know for sure?

Comment: @MattPayne: `head \`which django-admin\`` should tell you what interpreter will be used. It'll almost certainly be the wrong Python version.

Comment: @MattPayne I ask because your install info you posted isn't installing anything, it's letting you know it found a previous version and is skipping the install. What does `which python` output?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters It's saying ~bin/django-admin.py which I'm pretty sure is the local virtualenv version. But now I see that even with "install -I" it's downloading the correct version but installing the old one (see the edit I posted above) PS thanks for sticking with this so far.

Comment: Do you have system site packages enabled for your Virtualenv?  If so, I would suggest turning it off.  It tends to break things.

Comment: @Kevin I used "--no-site-packages"   is that enough? Or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: That should be fine (though the "correct" way is to pass no options and let it default to no site packages).  I'm stumped.

Comment: Isn't `django-admin.py` the wrong command now? I thought they switched it to just `django-admin`, can you try running that instead? See if there's a binary without the `.py` extension at the end?

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem while trying to upgrade Django from 1.6.2 to 1.7.10.  I kept getting 1.6.11 instead.  I discovered that the version of django-debug-toolbar I had pinned my install to wouldn't work with anything higher than 1.6.x so it was downgrading my Django version to 1.6.11.   This is something else to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that WebFaction has a system-wide site customization policy that injects `$HOME/lib/pythonX.Y` into your Python search path. This was put into place many years ago, before virtualenv was widely used. For some reason, virtualenv can't seem to ignore a system-wide policy like this.

The solution is to override the system policy by creating an empty `sitecustomize.py` in your virtualenv's `lib/pythonX.Y` directory, eg:

```
touch /home/you/path/to/virtualenv/lib/pythonX.Y/sitecustomize.py
```

Then reactivate your virtualenv.